# How to freeze Notification bar space when use CoordinatorLayout with scrollFlag=scroll?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I use CoordinatorLayout for scrolling out ToolBar. When ToolBar scrolls out, the background of Notification bar scrolls out also. It looks ugly. How to freeze the background of Notification bar?

Red "hello" line is mock of additional bar element. It has to don't scroll out of screen.

Screenshots of scrolling from this

[image]

to this

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ru.jollydroid.collapsingtoolbardemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:text="hello"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/content_main"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Full source: https://github.com/tseglevskiy/CollapsingToolbarDemo

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the line

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

from `CoordinatorLayout`
Since the `CoordinatorLayout` shouldn't fit the whole system window.